# How would I get a locale-based short date string for Android?

Tags: android, date, localization

I'm trying to get a date string with the shortened form of the day of week and month, in addition to the day of month.

For example, a user with an English locale would see:

Tue Jun 17

and a user with a German locale would see:

Di. 17 Juni

I've been looking at the `android.text.format.DateFormat` docs and the `getBestDateTimePattern(Locale locale, String skeleton)` looked like it might work, but it requires API 18+, so I can't use it.

Is there a way to get this kind of short format that is based on the user's current locale?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I think I finally figured this out:

```
int flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | 
            DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR | 
            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL | 
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY;

dateTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, millis, flags));
```

For an English locale, you get:

Wed, Jun 18

and for a German locale, you get:

Mi., 18. Juni

and for a French locale, you get:

mer. 18 juin

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`getMeduimDateFormat(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getMediumDateFormat%28android.content.Context%29), this obeys the current locale and the user's preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was close but not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
public class DateFormatDemoSO {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int style = DateFormat.MEDIUM;
    //Also try with style = DateFormat.FULL and DateFormat.SHORT
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df;
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.UK);
    System.out.println("United Kingdom: " + df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.US);
    System.out.println("USA: " + df.format(date));   
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.FRANCE);
    System.out.println("France: " + df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.ITALY);
    System.out.println("Italy: " + df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.JAPAN);
    System.out.println("Japan: " + df.format(date));
  }
}
```

for more info see the below link :-

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/DateFormatwithLocale.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Those date strings were too long however.

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

Use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "S-" ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.getDefault() ); // "S" for short date format. "-" to suppress the time portion. Specify locale for cultural rules about how to format a String representation.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( someDateObject, DateTimeZone.getDefault() ); // Convert a java.util.Date object to an org.joda.time.DateTime object. Specify time zone to assign to DateTime.
String output = formatter.print( dateTime ); // Generate String representation of date-time value.
```

Comment: Hi Basil thanks for your answer.  I do need to look into Joda Time, as I keep hearing a lot about it, but for now I've solved the problem in the answer that I posted.